# Do Lightroom lens correction profiles for Contax G lenses (e.g. 90/2.8) exist?

Tags: lightroom, old-lenses, lens-correction, contax

I recently acquired a used Contax G 90/2.8 Sonnar lens, which is an amazing piece of glass and was wondering did anyone make lens correction profiles for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you can check the [list of supported lens profile directly](http://helpx.adobe.com/x-productkb/multi/lens-profile-support-lightroom-4.html) to the adobe site.
The contax lenses seems not yet supported.
In this case you have three alternatives:

Submit a request in the  [feedback.photoshop.com](http://feedback.photoshop.com/photoshop_family) and waiting for Adobe implements in the new release of camera raw

Create a lens profile by yourself using the [lens profile creator](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/lensprofile_creator/) by Adobe. Note – the Creation process is fairly involved,  so if you decide not to create your own, you can use the Lens Profile Downloader to see if anyone from the community has created on that you can download and use it.

Googling for a custom lens profile made by some other user

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if one already exists, however you can make your own if you don't mind putting in some effort.  Adobe has the "Adobe Lens Profile Creation" utility which allows you to print a black and white checkerboard grid which you can then photograph and use to build a profile.  The documentation for the utility is available from Adobe's website [here](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/products/photoshop/pdfs/lensprofile_creator_userguide.pdf).  The utility itself can be downloaded [here](http://www.adobe.com/products/photoshop/extend.displayTab2.html#resources).